# Getting data from jQuery Deffered function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a JavaScript function that calls and gets a users cars for there area - it is as below:

```
function getCars(userId) {
    var cars = $.Deferred();
    var listOfCars = [];

    // Iterate over all areas
    $.when.apply($, $.map(areas, function (area) {
        return $.when(getCarsForArea(area, userId)).then(function (result) {
            $.merge(list, result);
        });
    })).done(function () {
        cars.resolve(list);
    });

    return cars.promise();
}
```

I then have another deferred that I want to use passing in the result of the function above.

so like

```
var userCars = $.Deferred();

var result = getCars('1234');  //User 12345 
userCars .resolve(result);
```

and later I have in a function

```
$.when(userCars).then(function (carsForUser) {
    console.log(carsForUser);
// rest of method removed for brevity
```

however in my console I am getting jQuery promise objects logged rather that BMW, Mercedes, etc - i.e - the data from the getCars method.

Is there something I am missing in the way I have wired this up?

Comment: Are you logging `userCars` or `carsForUser` where you get promise objects?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var userCars = $.Deferred();
> var result = getCars('1234');  //User 12345 
> userCars .resolve(result);
> ```

jQuery does no unwrapping of promises in `.resolve`. Here, `result` is a promise (the one you returned from `getCars()`), and therefore `userCars` will become a promise of a promise. That's why `carsForUser` will be the `result` promise in your `then` callback.

This deferred is totally superflous here. Just do

```
var userCars = getCars('1234'); // User 12345
```

and your code will work.

---

Apart from that, your `getCars` function is using the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). You should simplify it to

```
function getCars(userId) {
    // Iterate over all areas
    return $.when.apply($, $.map(areas, function (area) {
        return getCarsForArea(area, userId);
    })).then(Array.prototype.concat.bind([]));
    /* if you're less adventurous, use
    .then(function() {
        var listOfCars = [];
        for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
            $.merge(listOfCars, arguments[i]);
        return listOfCars;
    }); */
}
getCars('1234').then(function (carsForUser) {
    console.log(carsForUser);
    …
});
```

Comment: See "e" at close of `listOfCars` at comment including `$.merge(listOfCarse, arguments[i]);` .  What is expected result of `.then(Array.prototype.concat.bind([]));` ?

Comment: @guest271314: Pretty much the same as the commented-out version :-)

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat.bind([])` appear to return `function () { [native code] }` ?  http://jsfiddle.net/71u0642a/

Comment: @guest271314: you'll want to *call it* (with multiple arguments that are arrays), that's what `then` does after a `.when`.